# Subversion Host Unknown in Jenkins but can connect via Browser

Tags: svn, jenkins, proxy, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I can't use the `svn` plugin for jenkins, as our proxy only supports `NTML` authentication and this does not work with Jenkins as far as I understood.
So I made my job just checkout my repo like this:

```
svn checkout --username *** --password **** https://mysvnrepo
```

This fails due to the following error:

```
D:\Workspace\Jenkins\workspace\ProjectCI>svn checkout --username *** --password *** https://mysvnrepo 
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://mysvnrepo '
svn: E731001: Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt.
```

If I just click on the Hyperlink to my repo in the Jenkins log stacktrace, I correctly can access the `visualsvn` web interface and see my data. I don't get why jenkins is not able to find the host.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the IP address directly in the place of the link(http://mysvnrepo).

Comment: This is no giving me the error svn: E730061: Error running context: Can't connect to host. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. I don't even know, if the ip i get from nslookup http://mysvnrepo is the one of the machine or any proxy related address.

Comment: check the svnserver file if the proxy is set or not. If set then uncomment it.

Comment: I correctly set my proxy in Subversion/servers. I'm also able to checkout directly from command line but not jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `No such host is known`.

The error "no such host is known" means that the client is unable to resolve the hostname "mysvnrepo" as it is unknown on your DNS. You should contact your system administrator for assistance with this issue. That's not a problem with VisualSVN Server or Jenkins.